# Publish to MQTT in django Serializer save() method

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, mqtt, pika

I have a really simple API that uses django with restframework that act as an endpoint for iot devices.

iot Devices --HTTP POST--> REST API (django)
Data is validated and saved.

No need for any render or GET/PATCH/DELETE at all.

The only thing is that **I'm not saving to database** but I'd like to push to **MQTT** channel (other process that listen for messages will save/postprocess)

As I am not a django expert at all, My idea was to override the Serializer `save()` method that it actually does not save but publish.

MODEL

```py
class Meas(models.Model):
    SENSOR_TYPES = [
        ('temperature','temperature'),
        ('humidity','humidity')
        ]
    sensorType = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='UNKNOWN', choices = SENSOR_TYPES )
    sensorId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    homeId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    roomId = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    hubId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField()
    elapsed = models.IntegerField()

    objects = MeasManager()
```

SERIALIZER

```py
class MeasMQTTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    client = RMQPublisher(ch_name=rmq_chname,routing_key=rmq_routingkey,host=rmq_host,user=rmq_user,password=rmq_pass,port=rmq_port)
    class Meta:
        model = Meas
        fields = '__all__'     
    def save(self):

        logging.debug("Saving measurement")

        measurement = self.validated_data['sensorType']
        mytags = { 
            'sensorId' : self.validated_data['sensorId'],
            'roomId' : self.validated_data['roomId'],
            'hubId' : self.validated_data['hubId'],
            'homeId' : self.validated_data['homeId'],
            'elapsed' : self.validated_data['elapsed'],
            'last_seen' : self.validated_data['last_seen']
        }
        for a, x in mytags.items():
            mytags[a]=str(x)
        value = float(self.validated_data['value'])

        rmq_msg = mytags
        rmq_msg['value']=value
        rmq_msg['measurement'] = measurement
        MeasMQTTSerializer.client.pushObject(rmq_msg)
        logging.debug("Pushed to RMQ")
```

and RMQPublisher use just simple push to mqtt:

```py
class RMQPublisher(object):



    def __init__(self,ch_name,routing_key,host,user,password,port):
        self.routing_key = routing_key
        self.ch_name     = ch_name
        self.rmq_host    = host
        self.rmq_user    = user
        self.rmq_pass    = password
        self.rmq_port    = port
        pass


    def pushObject(self,object):
        self.connect()
        self.sendMessage(object)
        self.disconnect()


    def connect(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.rmq_user, self.rmq_pass)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(self.rmq_host,self.rmq_port,'/',credentials)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.ch_name, exchange_type='direct')

    def sendMessage(self,pushObj):   
        message = {}
        message["content"]  = pushObj

        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.ch_name,
                            routing_key=self.routing_key,
                            body=json.dumps(message))

    def disconnect(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

Approach seems to be half-working as some of the measurements as some
of the measurements are pushed but for some I'm getting an errors that I cannot really find a rootcause.

My guess it that with higher number of messages there is something going wrong with Serializer life-cycle that I might not understand propely

```
safeh-api      |     body=json.dumps(message))
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2248, in basic_publish
safeh-api      |     self._flush_output()
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1336, in _flush_output
safeh-api      |     self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 513, in _flush_output
safeh-api      |     self._impl.ioloop.poll()
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 576, in poll
safeh-api      |     self._poller.poll()
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 1200, in poll
safeh-api      |     self._dispatch_fd_events(fd_event_map)
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 904, in _dispatch_fd_events
safeh-api      |     handler(fileno, events)
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 391, in _on_reader_writer_fd_events
safeh-api      |     callbacks.writer()
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/diagnostic_utils.py", line 53, in log_exception_func_wrap
safeh-api      |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 1108, in _on_socket_writable
safeh-api      |     self._initiate_abort(error)
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/diagnostic_utils.py", line 53, in log_exception_func_wrap
safeh-api      |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
safeh-api      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 911, in _initiate_abort
safeh-api      |     'non-_STATE_COMPLETED', self._state)
safeh-api      | AssertionError: ('_AsyncTransportBase._initate_abort() expected non-_STATE_COMPLETED', 4)
```

Any tips for better design or fixing existing one will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: How big are your messages (in bytes)?

Comment: @hardillb around 300bytes

Comment: ok, your theoretical max is 650+ bytes. If your mqtt message ends up bigger than the MTU then you will need to run the network loop in order send them.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds like a paranoid solution but I ended up rewriting this simple API into 3 files flask-restplus application.
Same module for MQTT works as a charm, so probably it has something to do with my misunderstanding of django objects life-cycle.